# Allow attribute for authentication

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-identity

Almost all of my API endpoints are only by internal users, this is the default scenario, they need this access. When I create a new endpoint, they will need access to that endpoint.

I also have some special external users that can login, but only use a few of those endpoints, let's say 10%.

Instead of having to create a requirement/policy that allows all users, except external users, access (by decorating each API route with a policy `[Authorize(Policy = "InternalOnly")]` can I create a policy (or an attribute similar to `[AllowAnonymous]`), I put only on the API endpoints that external users allowed to access, something like:

```
[Route("GetForExternal")]
[HttpPost]
[ExternalAllowed]
public async Task<ActionResult<String>> GetForExternal(Request request)
```

In the old .NET identity I was able to this with a `AuthorizeAttribute`, but in .NET core it looks like requirements/policies are the way to go.

I used a `FallbackPolicy` in `Startup.cs` to make sure all endpoints are protected by authenticated users:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                         .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                         .Build();
            });
```

Comment: Just to be clear. Are you trying to use `[Authorize]` for internal and something like `ExternalAllowed` for external?

Comment: I could do that, but prefably I would add `[Authorize]` to all API endpoints, and then only put `[ExternalAllowed]` on the endpoints that are allowed by external users. Like whitelist concept.

Comment: Can internal users use methods for external users?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a Fallback policy:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(Policies.AllowExternal, policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser().Requirements.Add(new AllowExternalRequirement()));

    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                             .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                             .RequireRole("InternalEmployee")
                             .Build();
});
```

And decorating the external allowed api endpoints with the policy:
`[Authorize(Policy = Policies.AllowExternal)]`

And then adding a simple override policy:

```
public class AllowExternalRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}

public class AllowExternalHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AllowExternalRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AllowExternalRequirement requirement)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```